# Equivalence of Classical Nullstellensatz to "Affine schemes have points"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

- [The nLab page on the Nullstellensatz](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Nullstellensatz#ExistenceOfPoints) states:

> For $k$ an algebraically closed field and $I$ a proper ideal in the polynomial ring $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$, the set $V(I)$ (of $n$-tuples $\vec x \in k^n$ such that all polynomials in $I$ vanish when evaluated on these $\vec x$) is an inhabited set.
>
> we remark that an element of $V(I)$ is just a $k$-algebra homomorphism of the form
> $k[X_1, \dots X_n]/I \rightarrow k$.

I believe the map we are discussing is to consider each element $\vec x \in V(I)$ as the evaluation homomorphism , $\phi_{\vec x}: K[X_1, X_2, \dots X_n]/I \rightarrow k$ is the evaluation map which maps $\phi(p) = p(\vec x)$.

I don't understand why we need to quotient by the ideal $I$. Even *without* the quotient, it continues to be a homomorphism? We have that:

$$
\forall p, q \in K[X_1, \dots, X_n], \\
(p + q)(\vec x) = p(\vec x) + q(\vec x) \\
(p \cdot q)(\vec x) = p(\vec x) \cdot q(\vec x) \\
$$

1. So, why do we bother quotienting with $I$? What am I missing here?

They go on to say:

> Dually this is a morphism of affine schemes (ring spectra) of the form
> $\operatorname{Spec}(k) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k[X_1, \dots X_n] / I)$. Moreover since $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is the terminal object in this context, such a map is the same as a "point", a global element of $\operatorname{Spec}(k[X_1, \dots X_n] / I)$. Hence in this form the Nullstellensatz simply says that (for $k$ algebraically closed) affine schemes have points

I am quite lost at this stage.

2. I understand that $Spec(k)$ contains only the zero ideal $(0)$ since $k$ is a field, and hence the morphism is as good as singling out a single point. However, in what way is this a "terminal object"? In what *category* even are we discussing the above?
3. How is this equivalent to the (only) Nullstellensatz that I know, which states:

> **Nullstellensatz, statement 1:** maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[X_1, \dots X_n]$ are in bijection with points in $\mathbb C^n$?

> **Nullstellensatz, statement 2:** All maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[X_1, \dots X_n]$ are of the form $(x - C_1, x - C_2, \dots x- C_n)$ for $c_i \in \mathbb C$

I want to understand this form of the Nullstellensatz since it is the one that is used in "[Yuri Manin, Introduction into theory of
schemes](https://sites.icmc.usp.br/grossi/Sasha/galg/manin.pdf)". The textbook contains this as an exercise. I'm unfortunately unable to make sense of this.

Comment: It's true that they continue to be homomorphisms, but you quotient by $I$ so that you can identify "the same functions". Consider $I = (y-x^2)$. Then one of the elements of $k[x,y]$ is $y$ and another is $x^2$, but in some sense these are the "same" on $V(I)$. So by modding out, for one thing, you get rid of this redundancy.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Does this have some bearing on then deriving the weak nullstellensatz? Let me expand my question, since this is what I am really after: I don't understand why we need this condition

Comment: The name nullstellensatz and weak nullstellensatz are weirdly used for way too many related results. What I will say is if you're trying to establish a $1$-$1$ correspondence with points on $V(I)$ and ideals, then you need the $\text{mod } I$ condition, precisely because on $V(I)$, $I$ gives some degeneracy that would otherwise make this correspondence not $1$-$1$.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat You don't need the "condition" (I don't really view it as a condition, it's just that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ is the space of all polynomials on $V(I)$) for the statement to be true. But, it doesn't make sense to consider $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to k$ on $V(I)$ since there are repeat polynomials.

Comment: @DonThousandi: I expanded the question (by quite a bit I'm afraid, terribly sorry about that). It should now contain context of all the things I don't understand, and an answer to this question allows me to understand what I am missing. Could you please take another look? Thank you!

Comment: The "algebra" in algebraic geometry (at least in the beginning) is finitely generated $k$-algebras, which is the category in question. Once we see that a point corresponds to a morphism from $\mathrm{spec}(k)$, we can apply this to $k = \mathbf{C}$, and $X = \mathbf{A}^n_\mathbf{C}$. Here our $I = 0$, the zero ideal of $R = \mathbf{C}[X_1, ..., X_n]$. So such morphisms are in bijection with points of $X$, which are in bijection with maximal ideals. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph I don't understand why $I = (0)$. Are we interested to solve some system of polynomials? So why are we considering $I = (0)$? If we do consider $I = (0)$, the $V(I) = (0, 0, \cdots, 0)$ right? But this theorem only says that $Spec(k[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N]/I) = Spec(k[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N]/(0)) = Spec(k[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N])$ has points? how is that useful _at all_?

Comment: No, the $0$ function vanishes everywhere, so $V((0))$ is the whole space.

Comment: @ZhenLin Where did $V((0))$ enter into the picture? In the entire problem statement I wrote down, there is no reference to the vanishing set of an ideal at all? Moreover, I also don't understand how LetGBeTheGraph's answer says 

> So such morphisms are in bijection with points of $X$, **which are in bijection with maximal ideals**. 

How do we know that such points are in bijection with maximal ideals? Isn't that precisely the _statement_ of the nullstellensatz?

Comment: You wrote it in your own comment! Anyway, regarding your question: there are a few interconnected results called Nullstellensatz, but I do not think the bijection between points and maximal ideals should be counted as one of them. (The result I think of as being the most worthy of being called Nullstellensatz is the one that says $I(V(J)) = \sqrt{J}$ for any ideal $J$ of a polynomial ring in finitely many variables over an algebraically closed field.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's show the equivalence between two versions of nullstellensatz:

1. In terms of ideals, the theorem from the book says that $V(I) \neq \emptyset$ iff $I \neq (1)$, where
   $V(I) = \{ c \in \mathbb C^n : \forall f \in I, f(c) = 0 \}$
2. If $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $C[X_1, \dots X_n]$, then there exists
   $(c_1, c_2, \dots c_n) \in \mathbb C^n$ such that $\mathfrak m = (X_1 - c_1, \dots X_n - c_n)$.
   Also, every ideal of the form $(X_1 - c_1, \dots, X_n - c_n)$ is maximal.

Which I will write as:

- 2.a If $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $C[X_1, \dots X_n]$, then there exist
  $c_1, c_2, \dots c_n$ such that $\mathfrak m = (X_1 - c_1, \dots X_n - c_n)$
- 2.b Every ideal of $C[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ of the form $(X_1 - c_1, \dots, X_n - c_n)$ is maximal.

We can prove (2.b) by induction on the number of variables. When $n = 1$,
we have $\mathbb C[X]$ where all ideals of $\mathbb C[X]$ are of the form $(X - c)$
since it's a principal ideal domain. Also, the quotient ring $\mathbb C[X]/(X - c) \simeq C$,
since we will be left with polynomials of degree $0$ on taking reminders with
a degree $1$ polynomial, $(X - c)$. That is, we will be left with $\mathbb C$.
By induction on $n$, when $n = k + 1$, write the ring $\mathbb C[X, X_k, X_k+1]$
as $(\mathbb C[X, \dots, X_k])/[X_k+1]$.
Given some ideal of the form $(X_1 - c_1, \dots X_{k+1} - c_{k+1})$,
perform the quotienting as:

\begin{align*}
&(\mathbb C[X, \dots, X_k, X_{k+1}]/(X_1 - c_1, \dots X_k - c_k, X_{k+1} - c_{k+1}) \\
&=(\mathbb C[X, \dots, X_k]/(X_1 - c_1, \dots X_k - c_k))[X_{k+1}]/(X_{k+1} - c_{k+1}) \quad \text{(factor in terms of $X_{k+1}$)}\\
&= \mathbb C[X_{k+1}]/(X_{k+1} - c_{k+1}) \quad \text{(Induction hypothesis)} \\
&= \mathbb C \quad \text{(Similar to $n = 1$)}
\end{align*}

So the interest implications are between (1) and (2.a)

### (1) implies (2.a):

We know that $V(I) \neq \emptyset$ iff $I \neq (1)$. We wish to show that if
$\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $C[X_1, \dots, X_n]$, then we have
a point $(c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n) \in \mathbb C^n$ such that $\mathfrak m = (X_1 - c_1, \dots, X_n - c_n)$.
The proof proceeds in two stages:

1. Since $\mathfrak m \neq 1$, we have that $V(\mathfrak m) \neq \emptyset$.
2. We must have that $V(\mathfrak m) = \{ c\star \}$ for some $c\star \in \mathbb C^n$.
   For contradiction, assume not.
3. Then consider the ideal $J = (X_1 - c\star_1, \dots, X_n - c\star_n)$.
4. $V(J) = \{ c\star_n \}$. Clearly, $c\star \in V(J)$ since the polynomials $X_i - c\star_i$
   vanish at $c\star$. To show that this is the only point:
   if we have that for some point $d \in \mathbb C^n; d \in V(J)$,
   then we have that $d_i - c\star_i = 0$. This implies $d = c\star$.
5. Since $V(J) \subsetneq V(\mathfrak m)$, we have that $\mathfrak m \subsetneq J$ which contradicts
   the maximality of $\mathfrak m$
6. Hence, we have that every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ can be written as $\mathfrak m = (X_1 - c_1, \dots, X_n - c_n)$
   for some

### (2.a) implies (1)

We know that $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $C[X_1, \dots, X_n]$, then we have
a point $(c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n) \in \mathbb C^n$ such that $\mathfrak m = (X_1 - c_1, \dots, X_n - c_n)$.
We wish to show that $V(I) \neq \emptyset$ iff $I \neq (1)$.

#### Forward: $V(I) \neq \emptyset \implies I \neq (1)$:

we have an ideal $I$ such that $V(I) \neq \emptyset$. This means that
we have a point at which all polynomials in $I$ evaluate to $0$. But $1$ never
evaluates to $0$. Hence $1 \neq I$, or $I \neq (1)$. Formally, we
have $c \in \mathbb C^n; c \in V(I)$. That is, $eval_c(f) = 0$ for all $f \in I$.
But note that $eval_c(1) = 1$ for all $c$. Hence, we cannot have $1 \in V(I)$.
Therefore, $I \neq (1)$.

#### Backward: $I \neq (1) \implies V(I) \neq \emptyset$:

Since $I \neq (1)$, $I$ is contained in some maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.
This ideal $\mathfrak m$ has a point at which it vanishes, thus the ideal $I$,
a subset of this $\mathfrak m$ also vanishes on this point. Thus it cannot
have empty vanishing set.

We know that $c \in \mathbb C^n$ such that $c \in V(\mathfrak m)$.
Since $I \subseteq \mathfrak m$, $V(\mathfrak m) \subseteq \mathfrak(I)$.
Hence, $c \in V(\mathfrak m) \subseteq \mathfrak(I)$.  Thus $c \in \mathfrak(I)$.
Hence $I \neq 0$.